# Vue.js + Laravel5.7 'Hello World' Test not work

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

i want render Vue.js Code but NOT WORKING IN LARAVEL 5.7

My app.js Code :

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('hello-world-component', require('./components/HelloWorld.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

And New File HelloWorld.vue :

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    Hello Laravel + Vue!
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
  }
</script>
```

And welcome.blade.php :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title m-b-md">
                <hello-world-component></hello-world-component>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i run this command,

```
sudo npm run dev
```

result :

```
DONE  Compiled successfully in 6224ms                                                                   7:16:51 AM
       Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
  /js/app.js  1.38 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app
/css/app.css   198 kB       0  [emitted]         /js/app
```

but when i connect my index page, not showing my HelloWorld.Vue code.

i have no idea what is problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an element with id  `app` to mount to. For example:

**html**

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

**js**

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<hello-world-component></hello-world-component>'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

put an **id="app"** to your div

```
    <body>
        <div id="app" class="content">
            <div class="title m-b-md">
                <hello-world-component></hello-world-component>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

As DigitalDrifter wrote add `id="app"` and also add path to your compiled js assets.

Something like this (better before `</body>` tag).

```
<script src="{{asset('/js/app.js')}}" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Messages in your console can also provide you with some clues for further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You did not added id app in your blade

also you did not included script file which is compiled

**Update your blade**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>Laravel</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content" id="app">
            <div class="title m-b-md">
                <hello-world-component></hello-world-component>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```